# Accessing method parameter names in scala using java reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, sbt, java-8, compiler-options

I need to get a method's parameter name in one of my scala file. I know, by using `-parameter` compiler option, I can make this work in Java. However, I am not able to do this in scala,as I could not find -parameter option in scalac.

How can I achieve this ? 
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640617/how-to-get-parameter-names-and-types-via-reflection-in-scala-java-methods) answer in SO, but it is an old answer. Is it not possible in scala(2.11) as this option has come only in java8?  Is there any hack for it ?

EDIT: (adding sample scala code)

```
class ReflectionTest {
  def method(name: String, id: Long, desc: String) = {
    println("Inside the method");
  }
}
```

I am trying to read the method parameters of `ReflectionTest` class's `method()`

```
object Test extends App {
  val methods= Class.forName("com.reflection.ReflectionTest").getMethods
  methods filter(_.getName == "method") map { method =>
    val param = method.getParameters
    param.map {p =>
      println("Method : "+method.getName+" , Parameter : "+p.getName)
    }
  }
}
```

Scala version : `2.11.2`

JDK Version : `1.8`

SBT Version : `0.13.1`

Comment: Are you using SBT? If so, have you tried setting [javacOptions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Java-Sources.html)?

Comment: @andersschuller That is for compiling java sources right ? I have scala file, need to get the method parameters.

Comment: Sample http://stackoverflow.com/a/18580363/1296806 except use `paramLists` for deprecated `paramss`.

Comment: Scalac does this since 2.12.0-M4; see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9437